# LIne-by-line file-io not working as expected in Windows

Tags: perl, line-by-line

I'm using Perl 5.16.1 from Strawberry in a Windows environment. I have a Perl script reading very large text files. The smallest text file is 30M. When reading files that do not have a line feed at the end of the very last line I get very peculiar results. It may not happen all the time but when it does It's as though it is reading cached data from the I/O system for another file that I previously opened with the Perl script. If I manually edit the file and add a line feed it's fine. I added a line counter and some inline code to display what happens when I'm near the end of the file to make sure I wasn't going nuts. To try and fix I tried adding this to my script:

```
open (SS_LOG, ">>", $SSFile) or die "Can't open $SSFile\r\n $!\r\n";
print SS_LOG "\r\n";
close SS_LOG;
```

but it does nothing. The file stays the same size. I'm also storing data in large arrays.

Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: Maybe `$SSFile` isn't what you think it is? Wrap your fix with `printf "The size of %s is %d\n", $SSFile, -s $SSFile;` statements. (I predict the file will grow by 3 bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

Try unbuffering your output:

```
SS_LOG->autoflush(1);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it get flushed as it is being closed?